# Extending URLClassLoader and overriding getPermissions does not work

Tags: java, security

When trying to implement a sandbox in a plugin-like environment, I came accross https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580239/2057294 which seems to be exactly what I want, however I am unable to get it working, what am I doing wrong?

I have the following setup:

```
final class ModURLClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    ModURLClassLoader(final URL[] urls) {
        super(urls);
    }

    ModURLClassLoader(final URL[] urls, final ClassLoader parent) {
        super(urls, parent);
    }   

    ModURLClassLoader(final URL[] urls, final ClassLoader parent, final URLStreamHandlerFactory factory) {
        super(urls, parent, factory);
    }

    @Override
    protected PermissionCollection getPermissions(final CodeSource codesource) {
        PermissionCollection permissionCollection = super.getPermissions(codesource);
        //give no permissions to the codesource
        return permissionCollection;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(final String name, final boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null) {
            int i = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (i != -1) {
                sm.checkPackageAccess(name.substring(0, i));
            }
        }
        return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
    }
}
```

The idea here is that code loaded through the `ModURLClassLoader` may have no permissions at all. I do want to be able to add extra permissions statically in case I block some permissions which a mod would generally want to have.

Then I load up my classes via the following:

```
public class JavaMod extends LoadableMod {
    private ECSMod ecsMod;

    private ModURLClassLoader modUrlClassLoader;

    JavaMod(final Path modDirectory) throws ModNotLoadableException {
        super(modDirectory);
    }

    @Override
    protected void load0() throws ModNotLoadableException {
        try {
            Properties properties = ModLoaderHelper.getConfiguration(modDirectory);
            String jarName = properties.getProperty("jar");
            String entryPoint = properties.getProperty("entryPoint");

            Path jarPath = modDirectory.resolve(jarName);

            try {
                modUrlClassLoader = AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedExceptionAction<ModURLClassLoader>)() -> new ModURLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarPath.toUri().toURL() }, getClass().getClassLoader()));
            } catch (PrivilegedActionException ex) {
                throw new ModNotLoadableException(ex);
            }            
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(entryPoint, false, modUrlClassLoader);
            if (!ECSMod.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                throw new ModNotLoadableException(clazz + " does not implement ECSMod");
            }
            this.ecsMod = (ECSMod)clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ModNotLoadableException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void unload0() {
        try {
            modUrlClassLoader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ECSGame createGame0() {
        ECSGame ecsGame = new ECSGame();
        ecsMod.setupGame(ecsGame);
        return ecsGame;
    }
}
```

Which loads an untrusted JAR that has a class that implements `ECSMod`, I have confirmed that both the `clazz` and `ecsMod` belong to an instance of `ModURLClassLoader`.

Then the malicious code:

```
public final class UntrustedEvilMod implements ECSMod {
    @Override
    public void setupGame(final ECSGame game) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Where `ECSMod` and `ECSGame` are classes that belong to the plugin (also called mod) API and reside in the original classloader.

I'm running this without a security manager, as I believe that this would be unnecessary in this context? As the `ModURLClassLoader` defines the security.

Why is this not working, meaning that it still causes the program to exit, whereas I would've wanted an `AccessControlException`?

Comment: `System.exit` will call the `SecurityManager` in a similar manner to your `loadClass` method does. So when `getSecurityManager` is `null`, the permission wont be checked.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline It neither works when supplying the default security manager and granting all permissions, or is the key mistake there?

Comment: Granting all permissions to just the game and not mod code? / First place I would try debugging, I guess, is in `getPermissions` with `System.err.println(permissionCollection.implies(new RuntimePermission("exitVM.0"));`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline That printed false, implying that that classloader did not have permissions to execute such code... However I've now implemented it with security policy files, which seem to be working fine for this use case.